# How do I invoke a servlet without changing url?

Tags: java

I want to invoke a servlet without changing the url thorough jsp. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual methods are via [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) or an [iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5). Various libraries such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/) will do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you must include a servlet response in your JSP:

```
<jsp:include page="yourServlet" />
```

But this is poor architecture. The proper way would be to have a servlet which acts as a controller to display data on a JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Another (rude) way to do it is get the other servlet's response using java.net.URL.openStream() (or a similar call) and flushing the result to your servlet's output stream. However, as mentioned above, you're better off using standard AJAX techniques, or just a better OOP design.

Comment: but i dont want to use ajax.
it is possible without ajax?

Comment: Yes - As mentioned, get the content directly and flush it to the output stream, or include the servlet as a page (thx, Yuval)

Answer (score 0):

In JSP you can invoke any code in snippets.  I would suggest you change the program so that the servlet and the JSP both call a common method.  That is MUCH easier to code and test.

Answer (score 0):

It can seems a bit dirty but it's working... and generally used by marketing tracking services...
You can add a hidden 1x1px image to your jsp, with the url = your servlet. When trying to load the img, the servlet will be called by the browser...

http://yourservlet?args=...

This way you can call the servlet easily, but you can't treat the servlet response (or you just can show a different image to browser if needed...)